# How to know the default server of my web site in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, cassini

I made a website in asp.net with .NET 4.5 framework. I was studying about the differences between ASP.NET Development server (named Cassini) and IIS server.[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281667/asp-net-development-server-or-localhost-iis) I found out that IIS server is better than Cassini (for my purpose) but I don't know how to check the default server of my website. In the property page of the solution, under *Start Options* there are only two options under server. First is *Use default server* and second one is grayed out *Use custom server*.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392268/how-do-you-change-an-asp-net-website-to-use-cassini-server) is very close to my doubt but not properly answered. The exact choices between Cassini and IIS server appears under *WebApplication* project's properties NOT under *WebSites*.

I opened my IIS manager and when I tried to expand *Default Web Site*, error came **Could not find a part of the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'.**

How to know my default server and change it?

Comment: Open project settings, and switch to Web tab.

Comment: Project settings? You meant to say _Project Properties_ ?

Answer (score 0):

The default server are the APO.NET Development server (Cassini), but you can change that to either an IIS server or some other custom web server. You make these changes in your web project.

You can also set the option "Use IIS Express for new file-based web sites and projects" in: Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Web Projects.

Comment: that option you mentioned was already checked in the Tools-> ... ->Web Projects. Does that mean my website is running on a IIS server? Because I am able to see a (static) port number after localhost in the URL